# How can i find the unknown parameters in the following system of equations?

Tags: exponential-function

$$
f(t_1) = m + k\cdot e^{\dfrac{-t_1}{\tau}}  \hspace{1cm}  (1)\\
f(t_2) = m + k\cdot e^{\dfrac{-t_2}{\tau}}  \hspace{1cm}  (2)\\
f(t_3) = m + k\cdot e^{\dfrac{-t_3}{\tau}}  \hspace{1cm}  (3)
$$
The $t_1$, $f(t_1)$, $t_2$, $f(t_2)$, $t_3$, $f(t_3)$ are known (from three different measurements) and I would like to find the unknown parameters $m$, $k$ and $\tau$ from the above system of equations (1-3).
What is the easiest solution of the above problem ?

Comment: In the right hand side of each equation, don't you mean $e^{\dfrac{-x_i}{\tau}}$, for $i=1,2,3$?

Comment: Hi Marra, You have right. I have already corrected the equations. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate $m$ $$f(t_2)-f(t_1)=k\left( e^{-\frac{t_2}{\tau}}- e^{-\frac{t_1}{\tau}} \right)$$
$$f(t_3)-f(t_1)=k\left( e^{-\frac{t_3}{\tau}}- e^{-\frac{t_1}{\tau}} \right)$$ Make the ratio to eliminate $k$ 
$$\frac{f(t_3)-f(t_1) } {f(t_2)-f(t_1) }=\frac{ e^{-\frac{t_3}{\tau}}- e^{-\frac{t_1}{\tau}} }{  e^{-\frac{t_2}{\tau}}- e^{-\frac{t_1}{\tau}}}$$ and you are left with one nonlinear equation in $\frac 1 \tau$.

When solved, go back to get $k$ and then $m$.

**Edit**

If you are able to select the $t_i$'s, it would be very nice in arithmetic progression ! Let $t_2=t_1+a$, $t_3=t_2+a=t_1+2a$ and the last equation becomes
$$\frac{f(t_3)-f(t_1) } {f(t_2)-f(t_1) }=1+e^{-\frac{a}{\tau }}$$ then $\tau$.

Comment: and the main Problem is how we get that $\tau$ from this equation?

Comment: Except for very specific values, you would require a root finder (Newton method would be the simplest). Are the $t_i$'s in arithmetic progression ?

Comment: Thank you very much for these first answers. t1, t2, and t3 are three different time points, where i make my measurements. There are randomly selected. Would it be helpful if I selected these measurements time points after an arithmetic progresseion rule ?

Comment: @TheoD. This would be wonderful ! See my edit. However, what I suppose is that you wake more than three measurements. So, I suspect that some nonlinear regression would be required at a time. If the errors are small, the above procedure would give more than "reasonable" estimates to start.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Thank you very much. This is a very nice idea. I will start with this approach and I see how it is going.

Comment: @TheoD. You are very welcome ! Please, let me know. As an experimentalist, you face here a very interesting situation, be sure. Cheers.